# Combinatorics of kids and chairs

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $A,B,C,D,E,F$ be 6 different kids. We want to sit them in 6 different chairs in a line. The following affirmatives are true or false?

a) If the kids $A,B$ have always to sit side by side, the different forms of sitting them is $5!\times 2!$

b) If the kids $A,B$ has always to sit side by side and $E,F$ has always to sit side by side too, then the different forms of sitting them is $\dfrac{6!}{4!\times 2! \times 2!}$

I know a) is true (because $A,B$ can sit together in $5$ different positions, and they can change sits between them, and the other $4$ kids can sit in $4!$ different ways, so $5\times 2! \times 4! = 5!\times 2!$ is the answer (right?)). But what about b)?

Comment: Are chairs in a line or in a circle?

Comment: The chairs are in a line, I edited the post

Comment: For the second part, you need to clarify whether just each pair taken separately has to be together, or both the pairs have to be together and adjacent

Comment: Got it, I've changed the question. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you pair AB $\fbox{AB|BA}$ and $\fbox{CD|DC}$ they can be treated as two objects along with $E$ and $F$, and if the pairs needn't be adjacent, we get $4!2!2!$ arrangements

But if both pairs need to be adjacent, $3\times2!2!2!$ arrangements

Answer (score 0):

The expression $\frac{6!}{4!2!2!} = \frac{720}{24*2*2} = 7.5$ is not even an integer. So it is obviously wrong. The correct solution would be pairing AB and EF and finding four seats, then arranging each of them in $2!2!$ ways, giving you $4!2!2! = 96$, the same way you did part (a). Try to convince yourself with a smaller set of people(AB and CD, where A, B and C, D are paired, respectively).